# Как импортировать в .odt? Qt

Tags: c++, qt, импорт, open-office

Как лучше импортировать в .odt из Qt? Есть много примеров как в Word импортировать, но в .odt нет. Подскажите пожалуйста, желательно привести пример.

Comment: импортировать или экспортировать? если второе, то первая ссылка из гугла по «Qt OpenDocument Format export»: https://wiki.qt.io/Exporting_a_document_to_ODF

Comment: @Fat-Zer импортировать

Comment: родного в Qt ничего нету... особо распространённых библиотек, на сколько я могу судить, тоже, так что остаётся поиск на github'е... из свободных реализаций, например `okular` использует собственный парсер odt из внутренностей xml'я (основная часть порядка 600 строк), так что это не самый сложный формат для написания парсера с нуля...

Comment: @Fat-Zer а можно ссылку на okular?

Comment: [okular](https://okular.kde.org/) — это просмоторщик документов из KDE, так что чтобы собрать его влоб вероятно потребуются дополнительные зависимости. Конкретно парсинг odf в `QTextDocument` [здесь](https://cgit.kde.org/okular.git/tree/generators/ooo/converter.cpp)... Да, скорей всего это не полная поддержка формата. но думаю вполне достаточная... ЗЫ: как и остальные кеды, okular лицензирован под GPL, так что приватизирование сорцов может нарушить кармический порядок...